# Removing additional symbols on single points in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3, arcpad

I have problems with a point data layer in ArcGIS (9.3). An additional symbol has appeared on some of the points within the layer which were recently created and checked-in from ArcPad.  This additional symbol cannot be edited and has been placed on top of another symbol which I can edit normally using layer properties.  I would like to remove the additional symbol and retain a single editable symbol for each point.

I have checked the map as suggested in the answer below and have multiple symbols on single points in a single layer. How do I remove the multiple symbols and return to a single editable symbol?

The screenshot below shows an extract from the map (of trees).  The blue circle is the editable symbol covering all points in the layer.  The green circle is the additional non-editable symbol which has appeared for the most recently checked-in points.  I have selected two points labelled Betula and Quercus.  The selected point labelled Quercus has an additional green circle symbol, although that is not shown due to the selection highlighting.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Without more information it is going to be difficult to know which of about 4-5 possibilities is causing this.
1. you could have multiple symbolizations for the one point.
2. you could have multiple layers for the same data.
3. you could have multiple points at the same location.
4. you could have multiple data frames sitting on top of each other.
5. You created graphics.

Each point should be represetned by a row in your attribute table.
Select a box around all the symbols you are concerned with.
In the table of contents area switch to the "list by selection" view. 
This  will show which layers, and the number of objects selected in each (If you have all layers selectable).
Edit your question after performing this and report your findings.
**EDIT:**
here is a screenshot. try to do something like this and post back for clarification.
and explain it. "I have two points selected on the map. they are symbolized with the cross and the tap symbols. you can see them in the attribute table selected."
[image: pointdata].
I agree with fezter.
However I am unable to detect if you have two data frames or not from your screenshot.
It is probably one of the two.  You have one data frame named layers so if you don't have a second frame below it should definitely be the graphics already stated.

If so be sure to choose fezter answer.

Answer (score 4):

A possible reason for this may be that the features have been converted to graphics.  This will show the points, but will not allow editing.  Can you select the points using the Select Elements arrow?
[image: Select Elements]

If so, these points are graphics.  You can remove them or turn them off in the Annotation Groups tab. Right click on your data frame in the table of contents (called Layers in your example).  Select **Properties** and go to the **Annotation Groups** tab.  If there is an annotation group, you can remove it or turn it off.

[image: Annotation Groups]

Note, the above screen capture is from ArcGIS 10.0.  I'm not sure if it's different in 9.3.